# MySQL shuts down unexpectly

Tags: mysql

I was working on MySQL database all day and it was working fine.
I restarted my laptop and now the server won't even start, this is the third time this happens, every time i had to delete and download the server again.

The issue that on Xampp the server says its running for a split second then shuts down.

This is the error i get in the Xampp control panel.

> 4:50:48 PM  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
>
> 4:50:48 PM  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
>
> 4:50:50 PM  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
>
> 4:50:50 PM  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 4:50:50 PM  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing
>   dependencies,
>
> 4:50:50 PM  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method.
>
> 4:50:50 PM  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and
>   check
>
> 4:50:50 PM  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 4:50:50 PM  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 4:50:50 PM  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums

and this is the mysql_error.log

> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows
>   interlocked functions
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total
>   size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 out of 1 rollback segments are
>   active.
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for
>   temporary tables
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file
>   '\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file
>   full; Please wait ...
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1'
>   size is now 12 MB.
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence
>   number 21815; transaction id 9
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set
>   to 1 !!!
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from
>   C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at
>   200405 16:50:48
>
> 2020-04-05 16:50:48 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.

and I've checked the port if its being used but it is not, and just to be sure i tried to change the port still didn't work.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks,

Comment: mysql log says that it has startet. check if the service is running. This bug seems to go around. Also try ti start the service manually

Comment: I've checked the service isn't running, and I tried starting the service manually same result.

Comment: and the error log shows nothing and also the event viewer? could you check both please

Comment: The error is in the question, there is no event viewer because this isn't a service, i am trying manual run now